# Returning count() of items in last 30 days as part of LEFT JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

My current SQL looks like this -

```
SELECT i.id, 
       i.name,
       i.description,
       c.name campaign,
       count(h.id) hits
FROM items i 
LEFT JOIN campaigns c ON c.id = i.campaignid
LEFT JOIN links l ON l.itemid = i.id
LEFT JOIN hits h ON h.linkid = l.id
GROUP BY i.id
```

I would like to modify this so a 6th column is returned with the count() of h.id, but only including "hits" from the last 30 days.  So assuming that there were 100 "hits" overall and 50 in the last thirty days, the 5th column would be 100 and the 6th would be 50.

Apologies if my description is quite wordy...

Comment: Your description is not wordy, it's good. The clearer your question is, the better someone can answer it.

Comment: What is the date column? I mean the date and time when hits have been done?

Comment: The thing missing form your question is any information on what field would be used as the criteria for the date comparison.

Comment: I just want to point out that postgres has this functionality built in via window functions http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html . It's optimized so that you don't have to write sql that loops over your selected rows or has to do 2 queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT i.id, 
       i.name,
       i.description,
       c.name campaign,
       count(h.id) hits,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN h.hitdate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 29 DAY
                     THEN h.hitdate 
                     ELSE NULL
              END
            ) AS last_30_days_hits
FROM ...
```

You could use the shorter (but not necessarily faster):

```
       SUM( h.hitdate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 29 DAY )
         AS last_30_days_hits
```

Comment: I think `ELSE NULL` is redundant.

Comment: @Hamlet: yes, it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add a where clause no?  Something along the lines of...

```
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= h.hitdate
```

h.hitdate would be the date time field of the hit record.  If you are using timestamps simply calculate where h.hitdate >= (time() - 2592000).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 30 Days Filter in Either the ON Clause or the WHERE Clause as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN hits h ON h.linkid = l.id AND h.hitdate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

OR

```
WHERE h.hitdate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```